# show description when clicked

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

i will need some help with some coding if possible. I would like to have when clicked Learn More to show description above the button and when clicked back to hide it. Any help would be higly appreciated! Code listed below. Thank you for your time!

One more thing, as you can see the top border is not shown, how can i make it to show? Thank you very much for the time spent!

```html
 <style>
 
 /* RELATE PRODUCTS BEGIN */
.cardd {
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 
}
.cardd p {
 font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif; 
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 6px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 6px;
   
 }

.price {
 color: grey;
 font-size: 22px;
}
.cardd button {
 border: none;
 outline: 0;
 padding: 12px;
 color: white;
 background-color: #c41735;
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.cardd button:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
}
hr {
 display: block;
 height: 1px;
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}


 
 
 </style>
 
 
 
 <div class="container">
            <!-- <div class="row no-margin">
                <div class="col-lg-12  text-center">
                    <h1 class="section-heading">Harnesses</h1>
                    </div>
            </div> -->
            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1">
                <br><br><br>
                    <h1 class="section-heading page-heading">Engines</h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="height-60"> </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1 ">
                        <div class="cardd">
                     <img src="g" alt="" style="width:100%">
                <h2 class="page-heading">Vittorazi<br> Moster185 Plus MY20</h1>
                 <span class="price">£1729.99</span>
                  <p></p>
                  <p><button>Learn more</button></p>
                  <p></p>
              </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1">
                         <div class="cardd">
                     <img src="g" alt="" style="width:100%">
                <h2 class="page-heading"><br> </h1>
                 <span class="price">£1729.99</span>
                  <p></p>
                  <p><button>Learn more</button></p>
              </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1">
                        <div class="cardd">
                     <img src="" alt="" style="width:100%">
                <h2 class="page-heading"><br> </h1>
                 <span class="price">£1729.99</span>
                  <p></p>
                  <p><button>Learn more</button></p>
              </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <br>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-5 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="scrollReveal sr-bottom sr-ease-in-out-quad sr-delay-1">
                        <div class="cardd">
                     <img src="" alt="Atom 80 Vitorazzi" style="width:100%">
                <h2 class="page-heading"><br></h1>
                 <span class="price">£1729.99</span>
                 
                  <p></p>
                  <p><button>Learn more</button></p>
              </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </div>
               
                
            </div> 
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check out my answer i have posted a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the text hide and appear above the Button you must make use of `toggle()` event as

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
$(".collapsible").toggle(
function(){
$(".expand").css({"display" : "block"});},
function(){
$(".expand").css({"display" : "none"});});
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #c41735;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.expand {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand">
  <p>
    Hidden text.
  </p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Learn more</button>
```

**Note:** Add the Jquery CDN to use the jquery code.

(`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js">
</script>`)

Comment: If it helped you can you please accept it as answer.

Comment: It works when i put it on a empty HTML file, but otherwise removes the button when i replace the code, do you have any idea what it might be from?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a [collapsible](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp)! All you need is a little JavaScript, and you can expand/collapse text using a button.

### Expand Above

If you want to make the hidden text appear **above** the button, try this:

```js
var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
  collapse[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var expand = this.previousElementSibling;
    if (expand.style.display === "block") {
      expand.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      expand.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #c41735;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.expand {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="expand">
  <p>
    Hidden text.
  </p>
</div>
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Learn more</button>
```

---

#### Expand Below

If you want to make it appear **below** the button, however, just flip the order in which the `<div>` and `<button>` element appear, and switch out `previousElementSibling` with `nextElementSibling`:

```js
var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++) {
  collapse[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var expand = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (expand.style.display === "block") {
      expand.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      expand.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #c41735;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.expand {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Learn more</button>
<div class="expand">
  <p>
    Hidden text.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, gives me an error when i try to run snippet. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just a snippet. I've included the full code now. Try again!

Comment: No need to sorry! How can i make it to show above? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: This is not what the OP wants @ttoshiro wants the description to be appeared upon the button not below it.

Comment: @SimeonArsov you need to put the JavaScript under a `<script>` tag and the CSS under a `<style>` tag in the `<head>`. As shown: https://codesandbox.io/s/j73gk

Comment: @KunalRaut Fair enough, fixed. It's actually pretty much the same thing, you just flip the order in which the two HTML elements appear, and change `nextElementSibling` to `previousElementSibling`. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I just meant to say that the OP wanted the the text above the button please make the require edits:)